# find (′) at point (0,1/e).

Tags: limits, derivatives

find $ln(y')$ at point (0,1/e) where $xy^6-ln(x^8+y)=1$

I could not solve the question by taking normal derivatives. Is there a theorem here? how can i solve it.

Comment: You could first find $y'$ using implicit differentiation (differentiate both sides of your equation with respect to $x$, then solve for $y'$).

Comment: I calculated and found. Now I'm going to put the point (0,1 / e) in ln (-) right?

Comment: ı found the answer is -7

Comment: Right. I got $-7$ also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that $y(0)=1/e$, D. w.r.t. $x$

$$xy^6-\ln(x^8+y)=1, \implies y^6+6xy^5y'+\frac{8x^7+y'}{x^8+y}=0$$
$$\implies y'=\frac{-8x^7+x^8y^6+y^7}{6xy^5(x^8+y)+1} \implies y'(0)=e^{-7}$$
So $\ln y'=-7$.